# Get object instances in template using ModelMultipleChoiceField/CheckboxSelectMultiple in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates

With this code I managed to the get the object's pk and name (return value of the  __str__ method), however I need access to the object instance itself (I need some of its methods/fields in the template). How can I do that?

```
{% for value, name in form.stuffs.field.choices %}
    {{ value }} + {{ name }}          
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? If yes, please post that as an answer so that it could help others having the same problem.